# Make table scrollable to display all elements

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I have a `Table(...)` that consists some elements. Unfortunately there are to many elements and I got the following *error* message `Bottom Overflowed by X Pixels.`. So the best option would be to make the table scrollable. This means that if not all elements can be displayed, they should simply be displayed further down and the user can scroll down there.

Now my question is, how can I make the element scrollable?

```dart
          Center(
              child: Container(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    (isRecording == false) ?
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xC1D1FFC1)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        onRecording();
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        // <-- Icon
                        Icons.play_arrow,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                      label: const Text('Start Recording'), // <-- Text
                    )

                        :
                    ElevatedButton.icon(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: const Color(
                              0xC1FDA0AB)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        onStopRecording();
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        // <-- Icon
                        Icons.stop,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                      label: const Text('Stopp Recording'), // <-- Text
                    ),
                    (isRecording == true) ?
                    Table(
                        children: chunks.map((e) {
                          return TableRow(children: e);
                        }).toList())
                        :
                    Table(),
                  ]))),
```

Comment: How about wrap `Table` into `SingleChildScrollView`?

Answer (score 2):

You just wrapped the Table with SingleChildScrollView and added the Expanded widget to ensure that the SingleChildScrollView takes up all available vertical space.

```
 (isRecording == true)
        ? Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Table(
                children: chunks.map((e) {
                  return TableRow(children: e);
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Table(),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, when I press the button everything disappears.

Comment: Also the `ElevatedButton.icon`

Comment: Yes, it is disappearing because your Table view is not fixed it is in Expanded view so whenever you click the Expanded fill the whole sceen.
So first Wrap Table in to Sizebox with width and height try that it's working...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please provide an example ?

Comment: Sizebox(
   height : 500,
   weidth : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child : (isRecording == true)
        ? Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Table(
                children: chunks.map((e) {
                  return TableRow(children: e);
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Table()
 )
}

Use this code..